# Convert decimal to binary

Tags: beginner, c, number-systems

This program converts a decimal number to a binary number. This is one of my first C programs and I am wondering if I have used the elements of this language properly. Suggestions for improvement are welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_out_reversed(char string[])
{
    int index = strlen(string);

    while (string[index] != '\0')
        index--;

    for (int i = index; i >= 0; i--)
        putchar(string[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

void print_decimal_number_binary(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
    {
        printf("0\n");
        return;
    }

    char bits[sizeof(int) * 8 + 1] = {0};
    int index = 0;

    while (number > 0)
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            bits[index] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            bits[index] = '1';
        }
        number = number / 2;
        index++;
    }

    print_out_reversed(bits);
}

int main()
{
    printf("enter number: ");
    int number;
    scanf("%i", &number);
    print_decimal_number_binary(number);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Terminology

It's important to be able to understand (and describe) what's actually going on. Your program

1. converts from an integer decimal string representation to an integer using `scanf`. This integer is then represented as a binary number in the processor.
2. converts from that integer back into a string representation, but rather than it being decimal, it's binary.

So yes - it technically converts from "decimal to binary", but really it's "decimal string to integer to binary string".

### Use `const`

```
void print_out_reversed(char string[])
```

doesn't modify `string`, so write `const char string[]`.

### Simplify your `strlen` usage

This:

```
int index = strlen(string);

while (string[index] != '\0')
    index--;

for (int i = index; i >= 0; i--)
    putchar(string[i]);
```

can be

```
for (int i = strlen(string)-1; i >= 0; i--)
    putchar(string[i]);
```

It seems that you don't trust what `strlen` is doing, which is why you have that intermediate `while` loop. But that loop won't have any effect, because the null terminator will always be where `strlen` says it is.

### Use math instead of `if`

This:

```
    if (number % 2 == 0)
    {
        bits[index] = '0';
    }
    else
    {
        bits[index] = '1';
    }
```

can be

```
bits[index] = '0' + (number & 1);
```

### Use combined operation and assignment

This:

```
number = number / 2;
```

should be

```
number /= 2;
```

or, for speed (which the compiler will do for you anyway)

```
number >>= 1;
```

Comment: `int number ... number /= 2;` is not the same code as `number >>= 1;`  The first is well defined.  The 2nd `number >>= 1;`, when `number < 0`  the resulting value is implementation-defined.  `number /= 2;` is preferred for unambiguity.  Note: `(number & 1)` is incorrect code for the now rare _ones' complement_ platforms.  OP's code functions correctly on all - even if it is ponderous.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_bits(unsigned long long* num, char * out, int bytes);

int main(void)
{
    long long x = 0;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%lli", &x);

    char bits[sizeof(unsigned long long)+1] = {0};
    get_bits(&x, bits, 4);

    printf("%d in binary %s\n", x, bits);

    return 0;
}

//assumes char array of length 1 greater than 
//number of bits
//EDIT: VERSION WITHOUT MEMCPY AS REMINDED BY @REINDERIEN
//REMOVED aliasing issue
void get_bits(unsigned long long * num, char *out, int bytes)
{
    unsigned long long filter = 0x8000000000000000;
   // unsigned long long *temp = num;

    if(bytes <= 0) return;
    if(bytes > 8) bytes = 8;

    filter = filter >> (8*(sizeof(unsigned long long)-bytes));
    //memcpy(&temp, num, bytes);
    int bits = 8*bytes;
    for(int i=0;i<bits;i++) {
        //if(filter & temp)
        //if((filter >> i) & *temp)
        if((filter >> i) & *num)
            out[i] = '1';
        else
            out[i] = '0';

        //temp = temp << 1;
    }
    out[bits] = '\0';
}
```

### EDIT

Void* removed

### Improvements

The posted code requires several loops, divisions, and modulus calculations. While it does solve the problem of representing an integer in binary, the utility may be limited by additional clock cycles.

The code may be optimized and extended to use with other integer representations, including char, short, or long long (or long depending on the size of long).

One drawback of the posted code is the need to reverse bits.  Utilizing a mask to filter which bits are set in the number is more efficient.

### Alternative Solution

The function get_bits will accept any integer representation.

It will "return," really populate, a character array with up to a 64-bit bit representation of the number.

It *NO LONGER* relies on memcpy from string.h.

### Inputs for get_bits

unsigned long long* *num : a pointer to the memory address of the number to be represented in 
            binary

char *out : the address of a character array to store the bit representation.
            NOTE: This should be of length 1 longer than the number of bits to 
            be represented

int bytes : number of bytes containing the number to represent in binary

### Implementation

Based on the size of the data type of the number to be represented, a mask is established with the highest bit set.  This is the variable, filter, of type unsigned long long contained in 64-bits.  The input number passed as an unsigned long long*.  Using bit shifting, the filter is shifted to the right to align it with the highest bit of the number.

Ex. In hexadecimal, a 16-bit filter would be 0x8000, which in binary is 100000000000000.

Only a single for loop is performed to populate the output string.  In each iteration of the loop, a bit-wise AND is performed with filter and *temp.  The result of this expression is either 0 or non-zero.  The result is 0 only, when the highest order bit of temp is 0.  The position in the output string is set to 1 if non-zero or 0 otherwise.

At the end of each iteration the filter is shifted incrementally by 1 more bit to the right.

Ex. In binary, if temp is 1010, then temp << 1 is 0100. (a suitable filter would be 1000 in binary).

Comment: Why would you make `bits` a 64-character string if you're only scanning a 32-bit integer?

Comment: "One drawback of the posted code is the need to reverse bits. Utilizing a mask to filter which bits are set in the number is more efficient." You think so? Have you measured it? There's a third solution that uses your `void*` method, but can process input of an unlimited length (not restricted to 64 bits). Populating something in reverse is not slow.

Comment: Read through your own solution again. You aren't using one loop; you have a `memcpy` that isn't necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87897/discussion-between-reinderien-and-rjm).

Comment: Code assumes 8/byte. Reasonable, yet code could use `CHAR_BIT` instead of the magic number `8`.

Comment: OP use `char bits[sizeof(int) * 8 + 1] = {0};` and this code uses `char bits[65] = {0};`.  OP's code is better as it does not assume `int `width  limitation and right-sizes the buffer.  (Although I do not expect 128-bit `int` in the next 10 years)

Comment: `unsigned long long *temp = num;` is undefined behavior (UB) as it is not known that `num` is properly  aligned for `unsigned long long` access.

Comment: Please keep discussions in comments to a minimum. This post has been auto-flagged as having too many comments. Continue the discussion in the chat room above, and please remove any comments that are no longer relevant. Much appreciated ;-)

Comment: "Assumes little endian address" No, it doesn't? Why did you add this part? The advantage of shifts is that they are endianess-independent.

Answer (score 2):

> if I have used the elements of this language properly. Suggestions for improvement are welcome.

- Good use of `sizeof(int)` to form a right size buffer rather than assuming some magic number.

---

Improvements ideas

**Negative numbers**

Code only prints a `'\n'` (and no  visible text) when the `int` is negative.

**Unnecessary code**

The special test for `0` can be deleted ...

```
if (number == 0) {
    printf("0\n");
    return;
}
```

... by using a following

```
do  {
  ...
} while (number > 0);
```

instead of

```
while (number > 0) {
  ...
}
```

**Assumed `char` size**

Code assumes 8 bits/`char` with `sizeof(int) * 8`.  This is very common yet not specified in C.  Instead use `CHAR_BIT` for maximum portability.

```
#include <limits.h>

// char bits[sizeof(int) * 8 + 1] = {0};
char bits[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT + 1] = {0};
```

**Simplified code**

To well print negative numbers takes a little work to properly handle *all* negative values including `INT_MIN`.

Remember that `-number` is *undefined behavior* (UB) when `number == INT_MIN`.

Simplified code that forms the string right-to-left to skip the reverse step.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_decimal_number_binary_alt(int number) {
  int n = number;
  char bits[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT + 2];  // + 2 for '-' and '\0';

  char *s = &bits[sizeof bits - 1];  // Point to last array element;
  *s = '\0';

  do {
    s--;
    *s = '0' + (n % 2 != 0);
    n /= 2;
  } while (n);

  if (number < 0) {
    *(--s) = '-';
  }

  puts(s);
}
```

Sample

```
int main(void) {
  print_decimal_number_binary_alt(0);
  print_decimal_number_binary_alt(1);
  print_decimal_number_binary_alt(-1);
  print_decimal_number_binary_alt(42);
  print_decimal_number_binary_alt(INT_MAX);
  print_decimal_number_binary_alt(INT_MIN);
}
```

Output

```
0
1
-1
101010
1111111111111111111111111111111
-10000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: This will work fine but some cache memory guru will probably whine. It might actually be faster to loop from MSB and downwards in search of the first `1`, then write to the array from index 0 to n. As a bonus, the code gets far less cryptic.

Comment: @Lundin Such [sub-optimizations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210909/convert-decimal-to-binary/211001?noredirect=1#comment407991_211001) are selectively better or worse.  This code does less work for small values, unlike your suggestion.  What  part do you find cryptic?  Without UB, it does  show it handles the entire `int` range.

Comment: A line such as `*(--s) = '0' + (n % 2 != 0);` is not easy to digest even for veterans. Down-counting iterators in general make the code harder to read.

Comment: @Lundin Curious: How would you code `*(--s) = '0' + (n % 2 != 0);` to achieve similar functionality?

Comment: To begin with, separate iteration from assignment. Then I would prefer something  like `(n & 1) ? '1' : '0'`, given that this doesn't result in more branches in the machine code. And overall, I think the method I cooked up in a separate answer will have superior performance. Though it doesn't use the definition of "signed binary" as you do here, but assumes that there's raw data that may or may not be represented as signed though 2's complement.

Comment: @Lundin Yes using a separate line for `s--` tend to be favored - post amended.  Makes little difference to me so I try various ways and listen for feedback.  A weakness to  `(n & 1)` vs. `n % 2 != 0` is that the first  is incorrect functionality for those rusting out ones' complement machines. Still I tend to code for high portability avoiding assuming `int` encoding, width or even 8-bit bytes.

Comment: To write code so that it is _not_ portable to non-8-bit bytes, _not_ portable to one's complement computers, _not_ supporting EBCDIC etc etc is a feature, not a limitation. Those who insist on using exotic/fictional/bad architectures can do the porting. Everyone wins, except the guy who demands that obsolete TI DSPs from early 1990s must be used in new designs.

Comment: @Lundin Sure, non-8 bit byte and non-2's complement machines can be given little attention, yet endian, integer size, and many other implementation aspects of C's  are not universal.  One of C's greatest advantages is its portability to new and cutting edge architectures precisely because it does not over specify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88009/discussion-between-chux-and-lundin).

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding another answer in a different direction from my previous one, both to show the OP some alternative techniques, and to illustrate an adaptation of @RJM's method.

Here's the code; it's quite simple:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void printBinary(const uint8_t *restrict num, int bytes) {
    for (int p = bytes - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
        uint8_t x = num[p];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            putchar('0' | (x >> 7));
            x <<= 1;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int64_t x;
    for (;;) {
        puts("Enter an integer: ");
        if (scanf("%lld", &x) == 1)
            break;
        while (getchar() != '\n');
    }

    printBinary((uint8_t*)&x, sizeof(x));
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Things to observe as compared to the OP's code (and RJM's code):

- There are no calls to `malloc` or `memcpy`.
- The result is not stored in memory; it's output directly to `stdout`.
- The input integer has a primitive form of validation. The program will loop until `scanf` succeeds.
- The input integer supports 64 bits instead of 32.
- The output routine supports integers of any length, with the assumption that the integer is little-endian.
- The bit sequence reversal is done directly in the decoding loop, rather than as a separate step.
- There is no need for a "filter" (mask) variable.
- The main loop does not need an `if`.

### A brief word on computers

This code assumes a few things that are true in the vast (vast) majority of cases:

- The processor is little-endian
- There are 8 bits per byte
- The caller cares about the "real" binary representation of data in the processor, rather than the "logical" binary translation of variables

The last point applies to both signed and floating-point data. This code does not care to write "-10", because that's not how the processor stores the data. This code will show either one's-complement (never seen these days) or two's-complement (always seen these days) machine representations of the data.

Similarly, this code does not show "-0.5" as "-0.1" in binary. To do so would make the code more complicated.

### A brief word on `restrict`

For the dirty details, do some [reading here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict).

`restrict` is a promise that no aliasing is done; i.e. that this pointer is the only way to access the data it points to, to enable some optimizations that wouldn't otherwise be possible. In the context of this program, if it's self-contained, the keyword won't have any effect. `restrict` enables some optimizations that would make it invalid for other code to modify the same data. Even in a context where there is only one pointer argument to the function, `restrict` has meaning. A multi-threaded program could alias the data, or (though not the case here) this function could call out to another function that already holds an alias. These aliases and `restrict` cannot coexist.

I'm happy to explain any aspect of this approach for the purposes of education.

Comment: Cool. Would that '0' | (x >> 7) be encoded as a '1'?

Comment: @RJM Yep! Assuming that the MSB is 1.

Comment: Thanks. Good discussion.  Nice to meet you.

Comment: Note this code prints out `-2` decimal as a positive binary `"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110\n"`.  A reasonable expectation for a negative value in binary is `"-10\n"`.

Comment: Code requires 8/byte.  Reasonable, yet code could use `unsigned char` and `CHAR_BIT` to remove requiring the optional type `uint8_t` and `the magic number 8.

Comment: In my opinion `(x>>7) + '0'` is clearer than `'0' | (x >> 7)`. And of course `(x>>7) ? '1' : '0'` is the clearest, although I'm not sure if that would trigger the compiler to introduce an extra branch.

Comment: What's the purpose of `restrict` here since the function only takes one pointer parameter?

Comment: @Lundin - See notes in edited question.

Comment: Little-endian layout is hardly the "vast majority" of systems (even if x86 claims a big chunk of desktop processors).

Answer (score 0):

A decent compromise between readability and execution speed is this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

char* i32tostr (int32_t n, char str[32+1])
{
  const char NIBBLE_LOOKUP[16][4] = 
  {
    "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011",
    "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
    "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
    "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111",
  };

  char* ptr = str;
  for(uint32_t bit=32; bit>0; bit-=4)
  {
    uint32_t shift = bit - 4;
    uint32_t mask = 0xFu << shift;
    size_t index = (n & mask) >> shift;
    memcpy(ptr, NIBBLE_LOOKUP[index], 4); 
    ptr+=4;
  }
  *ptr = '\0';

  return str;
}
```

This reads the number 4 bits (a nibble) at a time from MSB to LSB. It masks out a nibble, then does a table look-up to get the pre-calculated string.

As it happens, a 4 byte string can be copied in a single instruction on 32 bit computers. Note the intentional subtle detail: `const char NIBBLE_LOOKUP[16][4]` instead of `const char* NIBBLE_LOOKUP[16]`. This means that the null terminator in the string literals is *not* stored and we can't use `strcpy`. Instead we use the significantly faster `memcpy`.

The local variables in the for loop are there for readability and don't affect performance. I could as well have written it as

```
for(uint32_t shift=28; shift>0; shift-=4)
{
  memcpy(ptr, NIBBLE_LOOKUP[(n & 0xFu<<shift) >> shift], 4); 
  ptr+=4;
}
```

But that's much harder to read and yields exactly the same machine code anyway.

In terms of execution speed, this should be much faster than parsing bit by bit and building up a string that way. The x86 disassembly looks pretty good; branch-free and cache-friendly: https://godbolt.org/z/DgJcVC.

---

Complete example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

char* i32tostr (int32_t n, char str[32+1])
{
  const char NIBBLE_LOOKUP[16][4] = 
  {
    "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011",
    "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
    "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
    "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111",
  };

  char* ptr = str;
  for(uint32_t bit=32; bit>0; bit-=4)
  {
    uint32_t shift = bit - 4;
    uint32_t mask = 0xFu << shift;
    size_t index = (n & mask) >> shift;
    memcpy(ptr, NIBBLE_LOOKUP[index], 4); 
    ptr+=4;
  }
  *ptr = '\0';

  return str;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void)
{
  char str[32+1];

  puts(i32tostr(0,str));
  puts(i32tostr(1,str));
  puts(i32tostr(-1,str));
  puts(i32tostr(INT_MIN,str));
  puts(i32tostr(INT_MAX,str));
}
```

Output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000001
11111111111111111111111111111111
10000000000000000000000000000000
01111111111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: OP's goal involves `int`. Many attributes here focus on a 32-bit `int`.  Not that that is bad, but not highly portable. In 2019 `int` is often 16-bit on many embedded processors and sometimes 64-bit on graphic ones. With that in mind, `0xFu << shift` should be more like `(uint32_t)0xFu << shift` to insure correct operation a 16-bit machine. Code uses `uint32_t` for `bit` and `shift`. Instead, code could well use `unsigned` here as forcing a type width could be counter productive. It wound be interesting how this code would be as `char* itostr (int n, char str[])` without assuming 32-bit `int`.

Comment: @chux You could use `INT32_C(0xF)` if you prefer. But this version isn't really feasible on small microcontrollers, as 32 bit copies will be heavy lifting there, and they won't have cache memory nor branch prediction. This code is intended for modern mainstream CPUs such as x86, ARM or PowerPC. Also, using smaller legacy architectures for new system design in the year 2019 is simply bad engineering in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Agree with most aside from implying designing for 16-bit `int/unsigned` is bad as such processors are made in the 100s of millions per year these days.

Comment: @chux Yeah but that's mostly because of the combination of skilled marketeers and incompetent engineers. For example, people still believe that 8-bitters are easy to use, because of some 20+ year old market hype. While the truth is that it's a pain to write C code for such legacy cores. I've been pretty much exclusively been coding for small, cramped, exotic MCU systems over the past 15 years. Nowadays, just use Cortex M, use `uint32_t` and relax. Hidden crappiness not included.